# SyntaxError: No se puede utilizar la instrucción import fuera de un módulo

Tags: typescript

Tengo un 'index.ts'

```
import * as Bot from "./src/main";

async function main() {

  var _Browser = await Bot.NewBrowser(true)
  var pag1 = await Bot.NewPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
  var pag2 = await Bot.NewPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
}

main()
```

y un archivo main.ts

```
import { chromium, Page } from 'playwright'

var Browser:any = null;

// Crea un navegador
async function NewBrowser(dev:boolean) :Promise<any> {
  if (Browser == null) {
    Browser = await chromium.launch({ devtools: true, slowMo: 500 })
  } 
}

export { NewBrowser }
```

El problema surge cuando quiero separar el main.ts del index.ts, ya que si coloco el código del main.ts en el index.ts, todo funciona perfecto, teniendo el código separado, necesito incluir `"type": "module"` en mi `package.json`, pero a incluir esto, node da un error interno de que no reconoce la extension de archivo .ts

este es mi [Package.json](https://pastebin.com/jE65v88b)

Comment: TypeScript !== NodeJS. Si estás trabajando con Typescript, necesitas transpilar tu código. Creo que tienes una confusión entre lo que es la sintaxis ES6 de Javascript y Typescript. Saludos

Comment: estoy usando ts-node

Comment: Sin ver tu `package.json` es complicado, no lo pongas en un enlace externo, copia y pega su contenido relevante aquí (en la pregunta). En teoría el comando `ts-node index.ts` debería funcionar. Lo que me lleva al siguiente punto, si estás usando Typescript, porqué usar `var` como declaración de variables?

Comment: Bro, mi package.json está en un paste.bin linkeado al final de mi pregunta

Comment: Bro, no todos podemos acceder a Pastebin por temas de proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu `package.json` el start script es incorrecto

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.ts"
 }
```

Node no tiene cómo correr TypeScript sin valerse de algún intermediario (como ts-node, pero no lo estás ocupando). Ahora bien... tu `index.ts` no tiene ninguna declaración de tipos, así que es un JS con la extensión cambiada. Node hace el intento de interpretarlo y se encuentra con una sintaxis de módulo, pero tu `package.json` no declara ser de tipo `module`.

Y salta el **primer** error:

```
 $  node index.ts 

 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Si conviertes el proyecto en un módulo:

```
"type":"module",
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.ts"
 }
```

Lo intentas de nuevo... y al menos avanzamos al **segundo** error:

```
  $ node index.ts

  TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
     for /proyecto/index.ts
```

Paso siguiente, usar `ts-node`, cosa que no estabas haciendo. Spoiler, también saltará un error:

```
   $ npx ts-node index.ts

  TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"
     for /proyecto/index.ts
```

Pero ya teníamos ese error así que no es propiamente un tercer error.

Paso siguiente, quitas `"type": "module"` del package.json. Esto es como volver al inicio salvo porque estamos usando un ejecutable que sí puede correr TS. Ahora sí tenemos el **tercer** error:

```
   $ npx ts-node index.ts

   TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
      index.ts:6:24 - error TS2339: Property 'NewPage' does not exist on 
      type 'typeof import("/proyecto/src/main")'.

      var pag1 = await Bot.NewPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
```

Y eso es porque `main.ts` exporta `NewBrowser` pero no hay nada llamado `NewPage` a la vista.

En la definición de tipos de playwright-core aparece que el tipo `Browser` tiene un método `newPage`... ¿Será ese? yo diría que sí. Entonces habría que crear las páginas desde el objeto browser y no desde el namespace Bot (que en realidad tampoco necesitas). La función `main` quedaría así:

```
async function main() {

  var _Browser = await Bot.NewBrowser(true)
  var pag1 = await _Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
  var pag2 = await _Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
}
```

Hacemos otro intento y nos topamos con el **cuarto** error

```
  $ npx ts-node index.ts

   var pag1 = await _Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
                               ^
   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newPage')
```

El problema es que tu función `NewBrowser` no retorna. En el `index.ts` la variable `_Browser` siempre es `undefined`.

```
       // _Browser será siempre undefined
       var _Browser = await Bot.NewBrowser(true)
```

Si tu intención era manejar una instancia global de `Browser`, no basta declararla fuera de `NewPage`. Los módulos no tienen variables globales implícitas. Pero podrías hacerlo usando `globalThis`

```
import { chromium, Page } from 'playwright'

globalThis.Browser = null;

// Crea un navegador
async function NewBrowser(dev:boolean) :Promise<any> {
  if (globalThis.Browser == null) {
    globalThis.Browser = await chromium.launch({ devtools: true, slowMo: 500 })
  } 
}

export { NewBrowser }
```

Apagando el modo estricto de TS este cambio permitiría, en `index.ts`, abrir una página con

```
  var pag1 = await globalThis.Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
```

Digo lo de apagar el modo estricto porque si no, te encontrarás con el **quinto** error

```
   error TS7017: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'typeof globalThis' has no index signature.

   globalThis.Browser
              ~~~~~~~
```

Se queja, con justa razón,  porque espera que extiendas la interfaz `globalThis` con tus variables globales. Esto tendrías que hacerlo en un ambient declaration y para este caso de uso no vale la pena.

Retrocedamos un poco. Dije más arriba que `NewBrowser` no está retornando nada. En vez de meter objetos en el ámbito global, bastaría con retornar:

```
var Browser:any = null;

// Crea un navegador
async function NewBrowser(dev:boolean) :Promise<any> {
  if (Browser == null) {
    Browser = await chromium.launch({ devtools: true, slowMo: 500 })
  } 
  return Browser
}
```

Esta implementación no contamina el ámbito global y de todos modos siempre devuelve la misma instancia de navegador. Con eso ya podrías abrir tus páginas:

```
async function main() {

  var _Browser = await Bot.NewBrowser(true)
  var pag1 = await _Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
  var pag2 = await _Browser.newPage("Titulo", "Descripcion")
}
```

Ahora _Browser, que al principio era `undefined` , es una instancia de `Browser`. Lamentablemente el IDE no es capaz de indicarnos eso. ¿Por qué?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es porque `NewPage` dice que devuelve `Promise<any>` que en realidad no aporta nada a la inferencia. Y nosotros sabemos que devuelve una instancia de  la clase `Browser`. Es un poco confuso haber bautizado la variable igual que la clase, máxime si la clase de por sí define un tipo. Mejor cambiémosle nombre. Algo como `_browser` serviría. Yo le pondría `browserInstance`  pero son manías mias.

```
import { chromium, Browser } from 'playwright'

let _browser : Browser;

async function NewBrowser(dev:boolean) :Promise<Browser> {
    _browser = _browser || await chromium.launch({ devtools: dev, slowMo: 500 })
    return _browser
}

export { NewBrowser }
```

Ahora desde el `index.ts` tienes intellisense, que es la mayor ventaja de usar TS:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y desde ya, nos está acusando que `newPage` no espera más que un parámetro, po lo que `Descripcion` no está haciendo nada. Esto es algo que hubiese sido muy difícil descubrir si no fuera porque TS nos lo indicó.

Comment: Sin palabras la verdad, un dios